# How do I group data for reporting on time ranges

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Long time reader, first time poster here. I am currently writing a DPS graphing program using c# and sqlite. I am wanting to create a histogram of the parsed data to show DPS in a graph form. The sql basically just stores the data in a database.

The problem I am having is that I cannot set up the bins for DPS. I'd like to increment each of the bins by 5 seconds. currently I calculate the amount of seconds which a raid takes place using the timestamp in SQLite, by taking the specific time of the event then converting it into seconds. I have converted the start of the raid and the end of the raid into seconds, but I wish to add a bin per five seconds to each of the logs in the database every 5 seconds. I really don't have an idea how to do this, all I have is the amount of seconds a raid takes place.

My code looks a little something like this

```
string selectName = "SELECT sourceName, sum(amount) FROM dataTable GROUP BY      
                         sourceName ORDER BY sourceName, amount";

QLiteCommand selectCommand = new SQLiteCommand(selectName, conn);
SQLiteDataReader dataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

//selects the time for the first encounter in a raid

string firstEncounter = "SELECT sum(strftime('%s', timeStamp) -
                         strftime('%s', '00:00:00' )) FROM dataTable WHERE ID = 0";

SQLiteCommand selectCommand1 = new SQLiteCommand(firstEncounter, conn);
SQLiteDataReader dataReader1 = selectCommand1.ExecuteReader();

string finalEncounter = "SELECT sum(strftime('%s', timeStamp) - 
                         strftime('%s', '00:00:00' )) FROM dataTable WHERE ID = " + ID;

SQLiteCommand selectCommand2 = new SQLiteCommand(finalEncounter, conn);
SQLiteDataReader dataReader2 = selectCommand2.ExecuteReader();

ArrayList names = new ArrayList();

Console.WriteLine(finalEncounter);

while (dataReader1.Read() && dataReader2.Read()) 
{
    firstEncounterSeconds  = dataReader1.GetInt32(0);
    finalEncounterSeconds = dataReader2.GetInt32(0);

    Console.WriteLine("total firstEncounterSeconds = " + firstEncounterSeconds);
    Console.WriteLine("final encounter seconds = " + finalEncounterSeconds);

    int totalFightTime = finalEncounterSeconds - firstEncounterSeconds;
```

the current amount of seconds which the raid has taken is 3774, I'd like to group each of the entries within a 5 second margin of each other to work out dps per 5 seconds. I hope this isn't being too noobish although I really cant get my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly it sounds like you're just interested in grouping your data points within a particular time range so you can provide some analysis on them. In your example, if you had three events at seconds 1,3, and 4 respectively you would want to treat those as being in Bin-1.

If that's the case then all you need to do is round your time data to the size of the bin you want. You could do that either by updating the original time stamp with a rounded value and then grouping on that or preferably add a new column to your data source, set it to the Bin the event belongs to, and then group by the Bin ID.

I might do something like this:

1. Add a column for SecondsSinceStart
2. Set SecondsSinceStart to the difference between raid start and event time
3. Add EventBinID
4. Set EventBinID to SecondsSinceStart / 5 (or whatever you want to group by)

As long as step #4 defaults to an int or you can make it do so, you now have a Bin ID for each event that you can group and report on. Bin DPS can be calculated by grouping on the Bin ID and dividing the aggregated sum by the number of events in that Bin.